# Which type of access token firebase give under user data?

Tags: firebase

Regarding to facebook access token. There are short-term and long-term
which short-term only for 1 - 2 hours and long-term for 60days.

[Facebook access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#termtokens)

[Extending Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending)

So which term of access token firebase server gives us as well as other third party login (web api)?

The reason I ask this is if firebase give us long term. I will skip the handling session expired code 1st.

Comment: Since it expires in 2 hours, can't you simply try?

Comment: I found this document https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/ How to handle expired token but it seems outdated and facebook recommend the new document. Which I listed in the question 'Extending Token' and extending token method required to do something at server side. Which we cannot.